# problems with reindexing dataframes: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: dataframe, pandas, reindex

I am having a real strange behaviour when trying to reindex a dataframe in pandas. My version of Pandas is 0.10.0 and I use Python 2.7.
Basically, when I load a dataframe:

```
eurusd = pd.DataFrame.load('EUR_USD_30Min.df').drop_duplicates().dropna()

eurusd

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 119710 entries, 2003-02-02 17:30:00 to 2012-12-28 17:00:00
Data columns:
open     119710  non-null values
high     119710  non-null values
low      119710  non-null values
close    119710  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4)
```

and then I try to reindex inside a larger date range:

```
newindex  = pd.DateRange(datetime.datetime(2002,1,1), datetime.datetime(2012,12,31), offset=pd.datetools.Minute(30))

newindex

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2002-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2012-12-31 00:00:00]
Length: 192817, Freq: 30T, Timezone: None
```

I get strange behaviour when trying to reindex the dataframe. If I reindex one larger part of the dataset I get this error:

```
eurusd[29558:29560].reindex(index=newindex)

Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

But, if I do the same for two subsets of the data above, I don't get the error:

Here's the first subset, with no problems,

```
eurusd[29558:29559].reindex(index=newindex)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 192817 entries, 2002-01-01 00:00:00 to 2012-12-31 00:00:00
Freq: 30T
Data columns:
open     1  non-null values
high     1  non-null values
low      1  non-null values
close    1  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4)
```

and here's the second subset, still no problems,

```
eurusd[29559:29560].reindex(index=newindex)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 192817 entries, 2002-01-01 00:00:00 to 2012-12-31 00:00:00
Freq: 30T
Data columns:
open     1  non-null values
high     1  non-null values
low      1  non-null values
close    1  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4)
```

I am really going crazy about this, and cannot understand the reasons of this. It seems like the dataframe is 'clean' from duplicates, and duplicated indexes.... I can provide the pickle file for the dataframe if you want.

Comment: What is the output of `eurusd.index.is_unique`? (perhaps when clocks change the time repeats itself unless you include that in the datetimes timezone info)

Comment: well, good question! I tried and it gives me False indeed... but how can this explain the different behaviour in the various sets of data?

Comment: very weird:if I type:
     
       
      eurusd[35700:35800].index.is_unique

it gives me True

but if I run

    eurusd[35700:].index.is_unique

I get False...

Comment: there is a repeated index is in `eurusd[35700:]`, one idea is to  split it up more to find it? :S

Comment: eurusd[35700:35701].index.is_unique gives me True
eurusd[35701:35800].index.is_unique gives me also True.... help...

Comment: Ooops, It's like [1,2,3].unique, [1].unique bit not [1,2,3,1].unique

Comment: exactly! I'm really lost on this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could groupby the index and take the first entry (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups)):

```
df.groupby(level=0).first()
```

Example:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2]], index=[1, 1])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   0
1  1
1  2

In [3]: df.groupby(level=0).first()
Out[3]: 
   0
1  1
```

Comment: thanks hayden, this make it work! Evidently there are some duplicated index, although I really struggled to find them in the dataframe... I really can't understand what's happening...

Comment: You can see where the duplicates are by `df.index.get_duplicates()` :)